# SocketIO events are not triggered when webapp is opened in mobile device

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

I am working on a simple app where events are triggered once user logs in successfully.

All the events are working fine in my laptop but when i login from my phone, no events are getting triggered? Any possible reason?

Added Angular socket service code below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
  public prod = 'https://afad.sdfsd.com';
  public dev = 'http://localhost:3001';
  public baseUrl = this.dev;
  private socket;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.socket=io('https://dfdsfs.sdfs.com')
   }
   public verifyUser=()=>{
     return Observable.create((observer)=>{
       this.socket.on('verifyUser',(data)=>{
         observer.next(data);
       })
     })
   }
   public setUser=(authToken)=>{
     this.socket.emit("set-user",authToken)
   }
   public userOffline=()=>{
    return Observable.create((observer)=>{
      this.socket.on('userOffline',(data)=>{
        observer.next(data);
      })
    })
  }
 
   public userList=()=>{
    return Observable.create((observer)=>{
      this.socket.on('userlist',(data)=>{
        observer.next(data);
      })
    })
  }
  public welcomeUser=(userid)=>{
    return Observable.create((observer)=>{
      this.socket.on(userid,(data)=>{
        observer.next(data);
      })
    })
  }
  public userOnline=()=>{
    return Observable.create((observer)=>{
      this.socket.on('userOnline',(data)=>{
        observer.next(data);
      })
    })
  }
  public disconnectUser = () => {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        observer.next()
      })
    })
  }    
}
```

I have installed `socketio-client` to achieve this functionality.

Any breakthrough will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I guess your laptop and phone are connected via WIFI to the router. If so you won't be able to use `https://afad.sdfsd.com` or `http://localhost:3001` due to them only being available only on the laptop.

Try pulling the hostname from the browser and use it as the base URL (`window.location.host`)

when you are using the laptop it will be `localhost:3001` and for the phone it will be `IP_OF_THE_3001`.

```
...
export class SocketService {

  private socket;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.socket=io(window.location.host)
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue here,
socket.emit will emit an event to only current user, We should use myio.emit in this case.